# Solr Dataimport nested entity from PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, solr, schema, dataimporthandler, data-import

I wanna create nested entity with `DataImportHandler`.
I use Solr 8.6, Postgress 12, openjdk-11.

My config (`schema.xml`) looks like this:

```
<schema name="products" version="1.5">

    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="_root_" type="int" indexed="true" stored="false"/>

    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

    <field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="price" type="float" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="categories" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="true"/>

    <field name="pictures" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="pid" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="previewUrl " type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
</schema>
```

data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
            driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
            url="jdbc:postgresql://${db.host}/myDB"
            user="user"
            password="myPassword"
    />

    <document>
        <entity name="products"
            pk="id"
            transformer="DateFormatTransformer"
            query="SELECT * from products"
            deltaQuery="SELECT id FROM products WHERE updated > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'::timestamp"
            deltaImportQuery="SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=${dataimporter.delta.id}"
        />

            <field column="id" name="id"/>
            <field column="price" name="price"/>

            <entity name="categories"
                query="SELECT category_id FROM product_category WHERE product_id='${products.id}'">
                <field column="category_id" name="categories"/>
            </entity>

            <entity name="pictures"
                child="true"
                pk="pid"
                query="SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE product_id='${products.id}'"
            >
                <field column="id" name="pid"/>
                <field column="preview_url" name="previewUrl"/>
            </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

This is the result I expect:

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "price": 10,
    "categories": [1, 2]
    "pictures": [
        {
           "pid":1,
           "previewUrl":"/url"
        },
        {
           "pid":2,
           "previewUrl":"/url"
        },
     ]
    "_version_":1674819829308063744
  }
]
```

But I get the following error:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: [doc=null] missing required field: price
```

What am I doing wrong?